# Ambiguous use of 'observeSingleEvent(of: with:)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I am trying to get some users' profile pictures. Here is the code I am starting with:

```
databaseRef.child("Users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in

}
```

I am trying to follow a Swift 2 tutorial; however, I am using Swift 3. I have tried to adjust the code already, but I have not been successful as I get the following error

> Ambiguous use of 'observeSingleEvent(of:with:)'

This error is on the first line. How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working solution for Swift 3:

```
databaseRef.child("Users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

})
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: You were using `observeSingleEvent` and in the answer you are using `observe` !? do they do the same job ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here with the block in the end of this line :

```
databaseRef.child("Users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in

}
```

since there is many implementation to the function `observeSingleEvent` the compiler is getting confused which to choose.

### Solution:

```
databaseRef.child("Users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, 
with: { snapshot in
    // Do whatever you want with the snapshot
})
```

Hope this helps someone